# is there anything out there that extracts information from unstructured text(news articles, books etc)

Tags: information-extraction

I have been trying to find a program that can extract information from unstructured text(news articles, books, etc).

My eventual goal is to create a program that can take regular sentences and cache it in a database much like google does but without all its duplicate information.

lets take the NLTK example: "At eight o'clock on Thursday morning Arthur didn't feel very good."

the things that i would want extracted would be:

time: 8:00pm

date: thursday

person: Arthur

action: didn't feel good

is there a program that can do this?

i have tried using NLTK but i cant seem to find any good way to accomplish extracting the information.

Comment: Roughly that's what any parser does. So yes. Your exact information categores, not exactly, although you'd come close with a some pretrained statistical parser and some kind of named entity recognition. Recognizing clauses that indicate dates is not a typical parser function but it shouldn't be hard to do either.

Comment: can you elaborate? @Junuxx

Comment: See http://www.nltk.org/howto/parse.html. Observe how the parse tree for "I saw John with a dog" identifies the 'persons' or noun phrases (NP) I, John, a dog. The action is one of the verb phrases (VP), things like time and location would be classified as prepositions (PP), e.g. "with a dog".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is called `Fine grained entity recognition`. No, There are no tools (except for research works) that can add such semantics.
To start with, you can recognise Person and Time with appropriate models using Entity Recogniser. 
You can recognise the actions from sentence parsing as suggested by @Junuxx. 
Also give [Wikify](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/demo_view/Wikifier) a try.
Thank you.